# How does selenium obtain api responses

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing

Selenium 4 using chrome_ Devtools does not support Python

How to obtain the interface information called during page automation testing.
Does selenium support obtaining interface responses, or do other Python libraries have convenient methods